# Selenium webdriver doesnt work in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium

I'm learning to use selenium and i'm writing a very basic program that works well if I run it with Headless mode = false but stops working as soon as I turn it to True. It doesn't work either if I open it without headless mode but alt tab while it's doing stuff.

I'm getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="email"]"}
```

This is the actual code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.headless = True



driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options = options) 
driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)


driver.get("https://www.compraensanjuan.com")


link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mi cuenta")
link.click()

email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email.send_keys("email would be here")


password = driver.find_element_by_name("clave")
password.send_keys("pasword would be here")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


print(driver.title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to wait a little, I suppose.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

PATH = "C:/bin/chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.headless = True



driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options = options)
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get("https://www.compraensanjuan.com")
time.sleep(3)

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mi cuenta")
link.click()
time.sleep(3)
email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email.send_keys("email would be here")


password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"formGroupExampleInput2\"]")
password.send_keys("password would be here")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


print(driver.title)
```

Output-

```
Ingreso a tu cuenta - Comprá en San Juan
```

Comment: This actually worked, thank you! Do you have any idea why it doesnt work without headless mode but alt-tabbed?

Comment: never mind I tested again and it works fine with headless off, I just had to wait.